# Measuring Semaphore wait times with Micrometer

Tags: micrometer

We have a throttling implementation that essentially boils down to:

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);
...
void callMethod() {
    s.acquire();
    timer.recordCallable(() -> // call expensive method);
    s.release();
}
```

I would like to gather metrics about the impact semaphore has on the overall response time of the method. For example, I would like to know the number of threads that were waiting for acquire, the time spend waiting etc., What, I guess, I am looking for is guage that also captures timing information?

How do I measure the Semphore stats?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things you can do depending on your needs and situation.

[`LongTaskTimer`](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_long_task_timers) is a timer that measures tasks that are currently in-progress. The in-progress part is key here, since after the task has finished, you will not see its effect on the timer. That's why it is for long running tasks, I'm not sure if it fits your use case.

The other thing that you can do is having a `Timer` and a `Gauge` where the timer measures the time it took to acquire the `Semaphore` while with the gauge, you can increment/decrement the number of threads that are currently waiting on it.